# Adding percentage to price

Tags: php, math, numbers, calculation

I'm working on a small project in which I need to add 1% to the price. This is going fine with most prices, but some give weird results.

F.e.

0.00034 * 1.01 = 0.0003434

but

0.00000034 * 1.01 = 3.434E-7

I need the above to result in 0,000003434, it does so in my calculator, but not in the PHP script. I tried all kind of things, like casting the number to a float, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want the right output, try `number_format(...,10)`.

Comment: That does the job, thanks!!

Comment: Cool! Glad to help